# Why is the number of Sylow $p$ subgroups relatively prime to $p$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

I am missing a small piece I guess. I am learning the Sylow's third theorem wherein we prove that the number of Sylow-$p$-subgroups ( lets call it '$n$' ) divides '$m$' where '$m$' comes from $|G|=p^k.m$ and $m$ is relatively prime to $p$.

Here we use the result that $|G:N(K)|=$(the number of Sylow-$p$-subgroups).

Therefore,
$|G| = n * |N(K)|$

which is
$p^k * m = n * |N(K)|$

$n$ divides $p^k * m$ and since $n$ is relatively prime to prime $p$, $n$ divides $m$.

I  want to know why is $n$ relatively prime to $p$?

Kindly help.

Comment: Sylow's theorem states $n\equiv 1\mod p$ which immediately implies $\gcd(p,n)=1$

Comment: Is it because modulo p, n=1?

Comment: @Peter can you please elaborate a bit. I too think I'm on it but something seems itchy

Comment: The gcd could only be different from $1$ , if $p\mid n$ , but we have $p\mid n-1$ which rules this out.

Comment: Thanks got that. The only divisors of p are: 1 & p itself. So for the Gcd(n,p) to be something other than 1, which in this case is p, p must divide n, but p|(n-1). Clear

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be the set of Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G.$ Write $n=|X|$ for the number of Sylow $p$-subgroups. The group $G$ acts on $X$ by conjugation, hence by the orbit-stabilizer theorem, $|\mathrm{orbit}|=|G:\mathrm{stabilizer}|.$ Now, any two Sylow $p$-subgroups are conjugate, so $|\mathrm{orbit}|=n,$ and the stabilizer of any $p$-subgroup $P$ is just it's normalizer $N(P).$ We thus have $n=[G:N(P)]=[G:P]/|N(P):P|.$ But $|P|$ is the highest power of $p$ in the prime factorization of $|G|,$ so the right-hand side contains no $p$'s in its prime factorization. Hence $n$ is relatively prime to $p.$

Answer (score 0):

By Sylow the number  $n_p $ of Sylow  $p $-subgroups is $1\pmod p $.  Thus $(n_p,p)=1$.